# Find the largest span between the same number in an array

Tags: java, arrays

Merry Christmas and hope you are in great Spirits,I have a Question in Java-Arrays as shown below.Im stuck up with this struggling to get it rite.

`Consider the leftmost and righmost appearances of some value in an array. We'll say that the "span" is the number of elements between the two inclusive. A single value has a span of 1. Write a **Java Function** that returns the largest span found in the given array.`

**Example:
maxSpan({1, 2, 1, 1, 3}) → 4,answer is 4 coz MaxSpan between 1 to 1 is 4
maxSpan({1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 1, 4}) → 6,answer is 6 coz MaxSpan between 4 to 4 is 6
maxSpan({1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 4, 4}) → 6,answer is 6 coz Maxspan between 4 to 4 is 6 which is greater than MaxSpan between 1 and 1 which is 4,Hence 6>4 answer is 6.

I have the code which is not working,it includes all the Spans for a given element,im unable to find the MaxSpan for a given element.

Please help me out.

**Results of the above Program are as shown below**

**Expected This Run

maxSpan({1, 2, 1, 1, 3}) → 4 5 X

maxSpan({1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 1, 4}) → 6 8 X

maxSpan({1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 4, 4}) → 6 9 X

maxSpan({3, 3, 3}) → 3 5 X

maxSpan({3, 9, 3}) → 3 3 OK

maxSpan({3, 9, 9}) → 2 3 X

maxSpan({3, 9}) → 1 1 OK

maxSpan({3, 3}) → 2 3 X

maxSpan({}) → 0 1 X

maxSpan({1}) → 1 1 OK**

::Code::

```
public int maxSpan(int[] nums) {    
    int count=1;//keep an intial count of maxspan=1    
    int maxspan=0;//initialize maxspan=0    
    for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++){    
        for(int j=i+1;j<nums.length;j++){    
              if(nums[i] == nums[j]){
                 //check to see if "i" index contents == "j" index contents    
                 count++;    //increment count
                 maxspan=count;  //make maxspan as your final count  
                 int number = nums[i]; //number=actual number for maxspan               
              }                            
        }       
    }    
  return maxspan+1; //return maxspan        
}
```

Comment: Smells like homework. What is your question?

Comment: im unable to find the maxSpan for a given element,my code aint working.

Comment: Please define "aint working". If I recall correctly, this is not the first time I asked a similar question to you. Always post compiler- or runtime errors/exceptions!

Comment: @Deepak, you can't expect people to just give you solution.  When you debug the program what do you see?  I suggest you add comments to say what each line is supposed to do and see if thats what the line really does. I would suggest at least four lines don't do what they should and you don't need *count* at all.

Comment: updated with comments in code

Comment: @Deepak, the comments are a good start. I suggest you read @marcog's answer. Its also a good start.

Comment: @Deepak, The reason I asked if it was home work is that the solution I would give would look nothing like a student's solution. Instead i/we are trying to help you work out a solution for yourself.

Comment: All of these solutions are very inefficient. Is there an efficient solution? (less than O(n^2) time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the following problems with your attempt:

- Your `count` is completely wrong. You can instead calculate `count` from `i` and `j`: `j - i + 1`
- You're overriding `maxcount` as soon as you get *any* span, so you're going to end up with the *last* span, not the *maximum* span. Fix it by going `maxspan = Math.max(maxspan, count);`.
- You can remove the line `int number = nums[i];` as you never use `number`.
- Remove the `+1` in the `return`maxspan+1;` if you follow my tips above.
- Initial `maxspan` should be 1 if there are any values in the array, but 0 if the array is empty.

That should help you get it working. Note that you can do this in a single pass of the array, but that's probably stretching it too far for you. Concentrate on getting your code to work before considering efficiency.

Comment: Thanks its working.you just made my day.Wish you all a Merry Christmas.I dont know how to make it more effeicent,if you could help me with effecient solution,it would help me to understand more.

Comment: You could do this in one loop if you used a collection. Just curious what solution you had in mind.

Comment: @Deepak, happy to help with a more efficient solution once you can work out a solution for yourself.

Comment: @Peter and @Marcog,Could you let me know how would you achieve it using a `Single loop`,since im unable to figure it out.you need a j'th index to compare with i'th index of Array,how would a single loop simplify that ?Please clarify.

Answer (score 6):

Since a solution has been given, here is a more efficient solution which uses one pass.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    int maxspan = maxspan(3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 5, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
    System.out.println(maxspan);
}

private static int maxspan(int... ints) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> first = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer>(); // use TIntIntHashMap for efficiency.
    int maxspan = 0;  // max span so far.
    for (int i = 0; i < ints.length; i++) {
        int num = ints[i];
        if (first.containsKey(num)) {  // have we seen this number before?
            int span = i - first.get(num) + 1;  // num has been  found so what is the span
            if (span > maxspan) maxspan = span;  // if the span is greater, update the maximum.
        } else {
            first.put(num, i); // first occurrence of number num at location i.
        }
    }
    return maxspan;
}
```

Comment: The algorithm is right, but the maxspan should be 1 when the array has at least one element. But I understand that the point of this post is to discuss the one-pass algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution of this problem:

```
public int maxSpan(int[] nums) {
        int maxSpan=0;
        int tempSpan=0;

        if(nums.length==0){
            return 0;
        }

        for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++){   
            for(int j=nums.length-1;j>i;j--){ 
                if(nums[i]==nums[j]){
                    tempSpan=j-i;
                    break;
                } 
            } 
            if(tempSpan>maxSpan){
                maxSpan=tempSpan;
            } 
        } 
        return maxSpan+1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it with a List. Easier way to do it.
The only problem is if the Array is too big, maybe it's gonna take a while..

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class StackOverflow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> listNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        listNumbers.add(3);
        listNumbers.add(3);
        listNumbers.add(3);
        listNumbers.add(2);
        listNumbers.add(1);
        listNumbers.add(4);
        listNumbers.add(3);
        listNumbers.add(5);
        listNumbers.add(1);
        listNumbers.add(1);
        listNumbers.add(1);
        listNumbers.add(1);
        listNumbers.add(1);
        listNumbers.add(3);

        int result = 0;
        Integer key = null;
        for(Integer i : listNumbers){
            int resultDistance = returnDistance(listNumbers, i);
            if (resultDistance > result){
                result = resultDistance;
                key = i;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("MaxSpan of key " + key + " is: " + result);
    }

    private static int returnDistance(List<Integer> listNumbers, Integer term){
        Integer startPosition = null;
        Integer endPosition = null;
        boolean bolStartPosition = false;
        boolean bolResult = false;
        int count = 1;
        int result = 0;
        for (Integer i : listNumbers){
            if (i == term && !bolStartPosition){
                startPosition = count;
                bolStartPosition = true;
                continue;
            }
            if (i == term && bolStartPosition){
                endPosition = count;
            }
            count++;
        }
        if (endPosition != null){
            // because it's inclusive from both sides
            result = endPosition - startPosition + 2;
            bolResult = true;
        }
        return (bolResult?result:-1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   public int maxSpan(int[] nums) {

    int b = 0;
    if (nums.length > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            int a = nums[0];
            if (nums[i] != a) {

                b = nums.length - 1;

            } else {

                b = nums.length;
            }
        }
    } else {
        b = 0;

    }

    return b;
}
```

Comment: Try this. I try to make it simple.

Comment: I run it codingbat. And it gives correct Answer for all sample input.

Answer (score 0):

One brute force solution may like this, take one `item` from the array, and find the first occurance of `item` from the left most, and calculate the span, and then compare with the previous result.

```
public int maxSpan(int[] nums) {
  int result = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    int item = nums[i];
    int span = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j<= i; j++) {//find first occurance of item from the left
      if(nums[j]==item) {
        span = i -j+1;
        break;
      }
    }
    if(span>result) {
      result = span;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Please review [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Just a code dump, even if it's correct and relevant, is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution -

```
public int maxSpan(int[] nums) {
  int span = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    for(int j = i; j < nums.length; j++) {
      if(nums[i] == nums[j]) {
        if(span < (j - i + 1)) {
          span = j -i + 1;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return span;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int maxSpan(int[] nums) {
 int span = 0;
 
 //Given the values at position i 0..length-1
 //find the rightmost position of that value nums[i]
 for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
   // find the rightmost of nums[i]
   int j =nums.length -1;
   while(nums[i]!=nums[j])
   j--;
   // j is at the rightmost posititon of nums[i]
   span  = Math.max(span,j-i+1);
     
   }
 
 return span;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public int maxSpan(int[] nums) {

//convert the numnber to a string
  String numbers = "";
 if (nums.length == 0) 
   return 0;
 for(int ndx = 0; ndx < nums.length;ndx++){
    numbers += nums[ndx];
 }
 //check beginning and end of string
   int first = numbers.indexOf(numbers.charAt(0));
   int last = numbers.lastIndexOf(numbers.charAt(0));
   int max = last - first + 1;

   int efirst = numbers.indexOf(numbers.charAt(numbers.length()-1));
   int elast = numbers.lastIndexOf(numbers.charAt(numbers.length()-1));
   int emax = elast - efirst + 1;
//return the max span.
   return (max > emax)?max:emax;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public int maxSpan(int[] nums) {
    int current = 0;
    int currentcompare = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    int internalcounter = 0;

    if(nums.length == 0)
        return 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        internalcounter = 0;
        current = nums[i];

        for(int x = i; x < nums.length; x++) {
            currentcompare = nums[x];

            if(current == currentcompare) {
                internalcounter = x - i;
            }

            if(internalcounter > counter) {
                counter = internalcounter;
            }
        }
    }
    return counter + 1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public int maxSpan(int[] nums) {
if(nums.length<1){
return 0;
}
int compare=1;
for (int i=0; i<nums.length; i++){
for (int l=1; l<nums.length; l++){
if((nums[l]==nums[i])&&(Math.abs(l)-Math.abs(i))>=compare){
compare = Math.abs(l)-Math.abs(i)+1;
}
}
}  
return compare;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static int MaxSpan(int[] input1, int key)
{
    int Span = 0;
    int length = input1.length;
    int i,j,k = 0;
    int start = 0, end = 0 ;
    k = key;
    for (int l = 0; l < length; l++) {
        if(input1[l] == k) { start = l;
        System.out.println("\nStart  = " + start);
        break;
        }
    }

    if(start == 0) { Span = 0; System.out.println("Key not found"); return Span;}

    for (j = length-1; j> start; j--) {
        if(input1[j] == k) { end = j;
        System.out.println("\nEnd = " + end);
        break;
        }
    }
    Span = end - start;  
    System.out.println("\nStart  = " + start + "End = " + end + "Span = " + Span);
    return Span;
}
```

Comment: Some text to explain your solution would be welcome.

Comment: This answer is not adding anything not provided in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4528129/1108890) or[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4528260/1108890) that was posted before yours.

Answer (score -1):

```
public int maxSpan(int[] nums) {

  int length = nums.length;  

  if(length <= 0)
     return 0;

  int left = nums[0];
  int rigth = nums[length - 1];
  int value = 1;

  //If these values are the same, then the max span is length
  if(left == rigth)
    return length;

  // the last match is the largest span for any value
  for(int x = 1; x < length - 1; x++)
  {     
     if(nums[x] == left || nums[x] == rigth)
       value = x + 1;    
  }

  return value;
}
```

Comment: This answer is not adding anything not provided in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4528129/1108890) or[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4528260/1108890) that was posted before yours.

Answer (score -1):

```
public int maxSpan(int[] nums) {

int count, largest=0;

for (int x=0; x< nums.length; x++)
{ 
    for (int y=0; y< nums.length; y++)
    {
    if (nums[x]==nums[y])
    {
    count= y-x+1;
    if (count > largest)
    {
    largest= count;
    }
    }    
    }
}

return largest;
}
```

Comment: Pls format your code, readiness is key to the answer. Add some explanation on your algorithm.

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.io.*;
public class maxspan {
    public static void main(String args[])throws java.io.IOException{
        int A[],span=0,pos=0;
        DataInputStream in=new DataInputStream(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter the number of elements");

        A=new int[Integer.parseInt(in.readLine())];
        int i,j;
        for(i=0;i<A.length;i++)
        {
            A[i]=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        }
        for(i=0;i<A.length;i++)
        {
            for(j=A.length-1;j>=0;j--)
                if(A[i]==A[j]&&(j-i)>span){span=j-i;pos=i;}
        }
        System.out.println("maximum span => "+(span+1)+" that is of "+A[pos]);

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static int maxSpan(int[] nums) {
    int left = 0;
    int right = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if (nums[0] == nums[nums.length - 1 - i]) {
            left = nums.length - i;
            break;
        } else if (nums[nums.length - 1] == nums[i]) {
            right = nums.length - i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return Math.max(left, right);
}
```

Comment: Not adding anything new to the earlier answers.

Answer (score -1):

The above solutions are great, if your goal is to avoid using Arrays.asList and indexOf and LastIndexOf, the code below does the job as lazy as possible, while still being clear and concise.

```
    public int maxSpan(int[] nums) {
           if(nums.length < 2){ //weed out length 0 and 1 cases
           return nums.length;
           }
           int maxSpan = 1; //start out as 1
           for(int a = 0; a < nums.length; a++){
               for(int b = nums.length - 1; b > a; b--){
                   if(nums[a] == nums[b]){
                   maxSpan = Math.max(maxSpan, (b + 1 - a));
                   //A little tricky getting those indices together.
                   break; //there's no reason to continue, 
                   //at least for this single loop execution inside another loop  
                   }
               }
           }
           return maxSpan; //the maxSpan is here!
        }

The Math.max method returns the larger of 2 values, one of them if they are equal.
```

Answer (score -1):

This is how I did it:

```
public int maxSpan(int[] nums) {
  for (int span=nums.length; span>0; span--) {
    for (int i=0; i<nums.length-span+1; i++) {
      if (nums[i] == nums[i+span-1]) return span;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This answer is not adding anything not provided in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4528129/1108890) or[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4528260/1108890) that was posted before yours.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure, if I have to use 2 `for-loops`... or any loop at all?

If not, this version functions **without** any loop.

At first you check, if the length of the array is > 0. If not, you simply return the length of the array, which will correspond to the correct answer.

If it is longer than 0, you check if the first and last position in the array have the same value.

If yes, you return the length of the array as the `maxSpan`.

If not, you substract a 1, since the value appears twice in the array.

Done.

```
public int maxSpan(int[] nums) {
  if(nums.length > 0){
    if(nums[0] == nums[nums.length - 1]){
      return nums.length;
    }
    else{
      return nums.length - 1;  
    }   
  }
  return nums.length;
}
```

Comment: You probably shall implement `maxSpan` with 2 for-loops, but there are several answers here that already did that. While this solves the task, I wanted to show that there is a more efficient way to solve it. I also understand that the author probably meant a different task (a "dynamic" maxSpan), but my solution fulfills all testcases, since those were too basic to show what the author wanted to do. So either his testcases are too basic, or my answer is correct and the task-text is too vague.

Comment: One testcase the author of codingbat should integrate would be `1 2 3 4 6 7 1 8 6` ... the correct solution would give 7, while my solution would give 8, therefore my code would fail.

Comment: Totally unrelated to the question. The question is about longest distance between 2 same values, it is not the size of the array.

Comment: @GokcenG: You are correct that this does not answer the question, but it fullfills the task with the given input and output (see original task here: http://codingbat.com/prob/p189576). Since the examples and testcases are somewhat poorly picked, you can solve the task by ignoring the original question. I have addressed this here: `I also understand that the author probably meant a different task`

Answer (score -1):

```
public int maxSpan(int[] nums) {
  Stack stack = new Stack();
  int count = 1;
  int value = 0;
  int temp = 0;
  if(nums.length < 1) {
    return value;
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    for(int j = nums.length - 1; j >= i; j--) {
      if(nums[i] == nums[j]) {
        count = (j - i) + 1;
        stack.push(count);
        count = 1;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  if(stack.peek() != null) {
  while(stack.size() != 0) {
    temp = (Integer) stack.pop();
    if(value <= temp) {
      value = temp;
    } else {
      value = value;
    }
  }
  }
  return value;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public int maxSpan(int[] nums) {
  int totalspan=0;
  int span=0;
  for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++)
  {
    for (int j=nums.length-1;j>i-1;j--)
    {
      if(nums[i]==nums[j])
      {
      span=j-i+1;
      if (span>totalspan)
      totalspan=span;
      break;
      }
    }
  }
  return totalspan;
}
```

Comment: Although it would be more efficient to start from the end of the array in the second pass, and break once a match has been found.

Comment: You can change according to your own comment.

Comment: This answer is not adding anything not provided in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4528129/1108890) or[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4528260/1108890) that was posted before yours.

Answer (score -1):

```
public int maxSpan(int[] nums) {
  int max_span=0, j;
  for (int i=0; i<nums.length; i++){
    j=nums.length-1;
    while(nums[i]!=nums[j]) j--;
    if (j-i+1>max_span) max_span=j-i+1;
  }
  return max_span;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Linear solution with a `Map` storing the first occurrence, and calculating the distance from it for the next occurrences:

```
public int maxSpan(int[] nums) {
  int span = 0;
  Map<Integer, Integer> first = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
  for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    if (!first.containsKey(nums[i])) 
      first.put(nums[i], i);
    span = Math.max(span, (i - first.get(nums[i])) + 1);
  }
  return span;
}
```

Comment: Not adding anything new to the earlier answers.