# java Array maxSpan

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Can anyone please explain the question and logic. I am not able to understand:

> Consider the leftmost and righmost appearances of some value in an
>   array. We'll say that the "span" is the number of elements between the
>   two inclusive. A single value has a span of 1. Returns the largest
>   span found in the given array. (Efficiency is not a priority.)

```
maxSpan([1, 2, 1, 1, 3]) → 4
maxSpan([1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 1, 4]) → 6
maxSpan([1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 4, 4]) → 6
```

Comment: Is there anything to explain? I don't see a question.

Comment: If you are looking for the solution of a riddle or something you should post it on Puzzling.SE.

Comment: I guess maxSpan just returns the length of the array?

Comment: It's not as if Google or StackOverflow had the answer to your question ... [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528016/find-the-largest-span-between-the-same-number-in-an-array)

Comment: can anyone help me to solve the problem am new to java

Comment: `maxSpan` is the position of the last element.

Comment: `maxSpan()` seems to return the distance between the first appearance of a number and the last one. In the first array you get `4` because the distance between the first `1` and the last `1` is `4` (extremities included).

Comment: for the second,third array which value is the leftmost and rightmost please sir @Oneiros

Comment: In both the second and in the third example you have `6` as the distance between the first `4` and the last `4`. The second one also have a maxSpan of `6` between `1`s

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/mirandaio/codingbat/blob/master/java/array-3/maxSpan.java

If you refer to the code hosted on GitHub at the link above.
As you can read in the documentation, the maxSpan function returns the (max) numbers of elements between two occurrences of a number. 
For example: 
maxSpan([1, 2, 1, 1, 3]) → 4
the first '1' and the last '1' elements in the array generate the maxSpan value of 4.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public int maxSpan(int[] arr) {

        int n = arr.length;

        if(n == 0)
            return 0;
        if(n == 1)
            return 1;

        int loIdx = 0;
        int hiIdx = 0;

        for (int i = 0, j=n-1; i < n && j>=0; i++, j--) {
            if(arr[0]== arr[i])
                loIdx = i;
            if(arr[n-1] == arr[j])
                hiIdx = j;
        }
        return Math.max(loIdx+1, n-hiIdx);
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what you did here. Just dumping code is not considered as a valid answer